# Find a directory in recursion in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to find a `myFile.helloworld_*` in recursion  inside modules directory the below script.But this is finding only in modules my `myFile.helloworld_*` exists in `modules/A` or `modules/B` also  i tried `use File::Find::Rule;` but I dont have the library I am not supposed to import them Is there a alternative way?

```
sub getFilePath() {
    my ($mwDir) = @_;
    my $modulesDir = File::Spec->catfile($mwDir, "modules");

    my $foundTest= 0;
    my $testDir;

    opendir (DIR, $modulesDir) || die "Error in opening dir $modulesDir\n";
    while (($filename = readdir(DIR)) and ($foundTest == 0)){
        my $temp1 = rindex $filename, "myFile.helloworld_", 1;
        if ($temp1 == 0) {
            $testDir = $filename;
            $foundTest = 1;
        }
    }
    closedir(DIR);

    if ($foundTest) {
        return File::Spec->catfile($modulesDir, $testDir);
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you looking "in recursion"?

Comment: He means "recursively"...

Comment: What do you mean by "I dont have the library" ? You do have "File::Spec" module, but not "File::Find::Rule" ???

Comment: `File::Find` is a core module in Perl 5. You have it, and it can search recursively, all you need to do is provide a wanted function.

Comment: use File::Find::Rule; I am not able to find   my @subdirs    = File::Find::Rule->directory->in($module_dir);

Comment: Can't locate File/Find/Rule.pm in @INC (@INC contains:

Comment: Yes, you already said that, there is no need to repeat yourself. You dont have `File::Find::Rule`, but you do have `File::Find`. They are two different modules.

Comment: Ok using File::Find what changes shld i make to above script?

Comment: @chiru Read the documentation at http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3A%3AFind. If you have problems, ask a question.

Comment: libclntsh.so is encountered a second time at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/File/Find.pm line 542.
 i get this now

Answer (score 1):

If it is only going to run on linux and you are OK with shell commands then you could do this:

```
sub getFilePath {
    my ($mwDir) = @_;
    my $modulesDir = File::Spec->catfile($mwDir, "modules");

    my $foundTest= 0;
    my $testDir;
    my $cmd = "find $modulesDir/ -name 'myFile.helloworld_*'";
    my @files = `$cmd`;
    die "error executing $cmd!" if $?;
    die "more than one found for $cmd" if $#files>1;
    return $files[0];
}
```